# API client framework or similar for PHP REST backend

Tags: web-apps, api, rest

tl;dr:
Looking for a client-side REST API solution that doesn't require learning about the past 10 years of JS trends, want to focus on the app logic, not the framework. Backend is not a problem, I got that.

---

I'm an old-school hobby developer who used to write web software with PHP before there were frameworks. I've been using Symfony for some years, looked at Laravel recently, want to create a new project (a trading game). I would like it to be open for future development and set up a REST API which I can then consume from a web frontend as well as a Unity 3D (where I've got experience) and maybe an Android/iOS App in the future.

Setting up the API side was easy for me, both with Symfony using api-platform and with Laravel.

But the client side has me stumped completely. I didn't do any web development for years and my last experience is Symfony + Twig. It seems the world moved towards Angular, React and Vue. I'm trying to wrap my head around those and I'm frankly speaking astonished that it seems incredibly hard to find a starter kit or something where JWT auth against a REST API is simply working. Found a dozen half-broken example Apps, and despite all the "up and running in 5 minutes" promises, I'm a far way away from being able to focus on my app instead of yarn this and npm that.

My goal is a simple web app to get the early adoptors into my game, and once it has some fans to collaborate with someone more on the client side to set up a better client on the same API. I'm looking for simplicity and functionality, and I want to focus on the contents, not the programming.

I've looked at Framework7, Onsen UI and Quasar but at least according to their documentation, they don't even have built-in JWT auth.

Maybe I'm just missing something very obvious, but I'd be thankful if someone pointed me in the right direction. At the moment I'm half-tempted to just ignore the API for my proof-of-concept implementation and go back to Twig or Blade.

The only thing I'm really tied to is Doctrine, though I might consider using a different backend as long as I can use a proper ORM (not just active record) and the learning curve is acceptable.